# Does anyone know the best way for components in Angular to share datas?

Tags: javascript, angular

Does anyone know the best way to send a certain data from one component to another component.
This means that for example if I sumbited an input text value in my (fixed navbar component), the submited value could be used in another components as if I submited those datas in those components.

Eg.

navbar.component.html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text">
  <button [routerLink]="['/search',text]" type="submit">Search</button>
```

searching.component.ts

```
this.searchterm = this.route.snapshot.params['text'];
```

I am trying to get the value submited in navbar.compnent.html and use it in searching.component.html at will.

The problem with getting it from the URL above doesn't work because it only gets the value when the searching.component page is rendered and not when the button in navbar.component.html is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like Angular, but one of it's weaknesses is communicating between two non-related components in my opinion. If they are child parent its pretty easy, but otherwise you need to use a service and a subject.

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchingService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    submitSearch(message: string) {
        this.subject.next({ text: query});
    }

    clearSearch() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getSearch(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then you can inject that service into both the navbar component, and in your search component.

When your navbar wants to submit a query, it can call searchService.submitSearch(query);

Then in your searchComponent you would have

searchService.getSearch().subscribe(query => //do stuff with the query);

You can also subscribe to the search result in any component, or submit searches from any component. So its very flexible, even though it takes a second to wrap your head around. The search service is a go-between and it uses observables to make it happen.

Comment: Check out 3 ways to communicate between Angular components => https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb